# Use Python zip to save data in separate columns from a binary file

Tags: python, file-io, binaryfiles

I have the following data file :

```
0.0 2453.4645   4906.929    7360.3935   9813.858    12267.3225  14720.787   17174.2515  19627.716   22081.1805  24534.645   26988.1095  29441.574   31895.0385  34348.503   36801.9675
```

in BINARY form.

I need to read this into 8 lists a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h with 3 elements each, . i.e. I need the elements 1-8 saved in each of these variables, and then 9-16 , and so on.

I have the following code:

```
 # Python code to read binary data

from struct import *
import numpy as np

readfile = open('bigdata.dat')

readfile_data = readfile.read()

type(readfile_data)

a = len(readfile_data)

print a

e = unpack('18d',readfile_data[0:8*18])

field_names = ('a','b','c','d','e','f')

hg = dict(zip(field_names,e))

print hg
```

What I get is a dict with an element for each dictionary value:

```
{'a': 0.0, 'c': 4906.929, 'b': 2453.4645, 'e': 9813.858, 'd': 7360.3935, 'f': 12267.3225}
```

How can I do this in Python (preferably 2.7, but 3 is also welcome)? I assume I have to loop
over these dictionary field names over the entire list, but I do not know how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itertools` module has an `islice()` function which may help you:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> import itertools
>>> for val in itertools.islice(s, 0, None, 8):
...   print val
...
a
i
q
y
>>> for val in itertools.islice(s, 1, None, 8):
...   print val
...
b
j
r
z
>>> for val in itertools.islice(s, 2, None, 8):
...   print val
...
c
k
s
```

So for your problem, you might do:

```
import itertools
a = [item for item in itertools.islice(e, 0, None, 8)]
b = [item for item in itertools.islice(e, 1, None, 8)]
c = [item for item in itertools.islice(e, 2, None, 8)]
```

and so on. Or, better yet:

```
columns = []
for n in range(8):
    columns.append([item for item in itertools.islice(e, n, None, 8)])
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. Here's the [documentation for islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). There are plenty of other useful tools in the `itertools` module: take a look!

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the `[x for x in some_iterator]` notation, it's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). They're very useful, and well worth wrapping your head around: using them will make your code much more concise, and also easier to read as long as you don't go overboard with trying to cram too much into a single line.

Comment: The "not going overboard cramming too much into a single line" thing is why I didn't use a *second* list comprehension in my final example. The pattern `somelist = [] ; for value in some_iterator: somelist.append(do_something_with(value))` is a classic sign that you should use a list comprehension... but in that last example, it would have ended up being *two* list comprehensions nested inside each other. Which would have worked just fine, but would have been very difficult to read unless you know Python very well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the data in list form you can do something like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[0.0, 2453.4645, 4906.929, 7360.3935,
        9813.858, 12267.3225, 14720.787,
        17174.2515], [19627.716, 22081.1805,
        24534.645, 26988.1095, 29441.574,
        31895.0385, 34348.503, 36801.9675]]

hg = defaultdict(list)
field_names = ('a','b','c','d','e','f')

for row in data:
    for field_name, datum in zip(field_names, row):
        hg[field_name].append(datum)

print hg
```

which outputs

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0.0, 19627.716], 'c': [4906.929, 24534.645], 'b': [2453.4645, 22081.1805], 'e': [9813.858, 29441.574], 'd': [7360.3935, 26988.1095], 'f': [12267.3225, 31895.0385]})
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for. He wants 'a' to have the 0th and 8th values, 'b' to have the 1st and 9th values, and so on.